# Is there a best practice integration of Braze with push_kit HMS - Flutter

Tags: flutter, plugins, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification

Do you know if there is any best practice or steps to follow to integrate **Braze SDK** with **Huawei push_kit** into a **Flutter** project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Braze supports Huawei Push and provides the Flutter plug-in. Therefore, you can integrate it by referring to the following document.

[Huawei Integration](https://www.braze.com/docs/developer_guide/platform_integration_guides/android/push_notifications/android/integration/huawei_integration/#step-2-create-a-new-huawei-app-in-the-braze-dashboard)

[Flutter SDK](https://www.braze.com/docs/developer_guide/platform_integration_guides/flutter/preview/)